# gmw from custom fields - frontend posting

Tags: wordpress, post, frontend

I'm trying to complete the address field of gmw from a form which publishes custom post type called `fiche_artiste`.

I use this code in my homemade plugin:

```
function gmw_update_fiche_artiste_location( $pid ) {

// Si c'est une édition d'un Artiste existant
if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $pid ) )
    return;

// Vérifie la sauvegarde //
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

//Vérifie les droit de l'utilisateur
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $pid ) )
    return;

//Obtention de l'information du champs du formulaire "address"
$gmw_address = get_post_meta( $pid, 'address', true );

if ( empty( $address ) )
    return;

//Appel le fichier update-location.php
include_once( GMW_PT_PATH .'/includes/gmw-pt-update-location.php' );

//Verifie si la fonction existe
if ( !function_exists( 'gmw_pt_update_location' ) )
    return;

//Crée un array à passer à la fonction
$gmw_args = array(
        'post_id' => $pid, //Identifie le nouvelle article 
        'post_type' => 'fiche_artiste',
        'address' => $gmw_address // L'adresse récupérée du champs adress
);

//Appelle la fonction
gmw_pt_update_location( $gmw_args );
}
//Execute la fonction à la création/mise à jour de l'article
add_action( 'gmw_pt_after_location_updated', 'gmw_update_fiche_artiste_location' );
```

but it doesn't work. My custom field called `address` is correctly filled but post localization is not.

Comment: It would help us all if you translate those comments and/or remove the ones that are not particularly helpful in diagnosing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
        'post_type' => 'fiche_artiste',// my custom post type
```

According to documentations.

ID's are unique, it doesn't matter what is the post type.

Answer (score 0):

I m really sorry, in fact this code works very well !
I just had to publish the new post from the backend! sorry again.